# Inheriting xpath string in Java using Selenium Webdriver and Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, inheritance, xpath, cucumber

I have this code as a part of a program to practice Cucumber, Xpath and Selenium:

```
@When("^I select Divany i Kresla from left vertical menu$")
        public void i_choose_Divany_i_Kresla_from_left_vertical_menu() {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='top-left-menu']/ul/li/a")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
```

It's pretty repetitive in every scenario, everything that actually changes is data I select (which I can move to Examples in .feature file) and xpath which I use to access elements on the page. Is there a way to somehow move this step to a generalized class and set it's xpath from inherited classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following step definitions and which takes sub menu name as input and click on it.

```
@When("^I select .* from left vertical menu$")
    public void i_choose_Divany_i_Kresla_from_left_vertical_menu(String menu) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='top-left-menu']/ul/li/a[text()="+menu+"]")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: however the better thing would be to use page object with Cucumber. Do not use hard coded identifier. put them into variable or use PageFactory.  else it might be a maintenance night mare if application goes through some changes in future.